# How to parse through json in Python with dynamic key names?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to pull `name` from the below JSON.  The problem I am having is the host name in the JSON is dynamic so I don't know how to dig below that layer if that makes sense.  So 'ip-10-12-68-170.b2c.test.com' has a different ip for each block of json.

```
{
    "host" : {
        "ip-10-12-68-170.b2c.test.com" : {
            "environment" : {
                "testing1" : {
                    "ip" : "ip-10-12-68-170",
                    "name" : "testing",
                    "env.root" : "/",
                    "host" : "ip-10-12-68-170.b2c.test.com",
                    "sin" : "sin.80",
                    "env.description" : "Content Author Preview"
                }
            }
        },
        "ip-10-12-108.27.b2c.test.com" : {
            "environment" : {
                    "esbqav" : {
                    "ip" : "ip-10-12-108.27",
                    "name" : "espv",
                    "env.root" : "/",
                    "host" : "ip-10-12-108.27.b2c.test.com",
                    "sin" : "sin.0",
                    "env.description" : "QA"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I grab `name` from this example?

Comment: To be clear, is the code sample in your question intended to be a JSON string or a Python program fragment?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using dictionary `values()` or `items()` methods, given that the structure is as in the example.

```
import json

json_string = """
{
   "host" : {
      "ip-10-12-68-170.b2c.test.com" : {
         "environment" : {
            "testing1" : {
               "ip" : "ip-10-12-68-170",
               "name" : "testing",
               "env.root" : "/",
               "host" : "ip-10-12-68-170.b2c.test.com",
               "sin" : "sin.80",
               "env.description" : "Content Author Preview"
            }
         }
      },
    "ip-10-12-108.27.b2c.test.com" : {
       "environment" : {
          "esbqav" : {
             "ip" : "ip-10-12-108.27",
             "name" : "espv",
             "env.root" : "/",
             "host" : "ip-10-12-108.27.b2c.test.com",
             "sin" : "sin.0",
             "env.description" : "QA"
          }
       }
    }
     }
}
"""

json_data = json.loads(json_string)

for host in json_data.values():
    for hostname in host.values():
        environment = hostname.get('environment')

        for env in environment.values():
            name = env.get('name')
            print name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over a `dict` by calling its `.items()` member. That way, you don't need to know beforehand what the keys are.

```
json= {
   "host" : {
      "ip-10-12-68-170.b2c.test.com" : {
         "environment" : {
            "testing1" : {
               "ip" : "ip-10-12-68-170",
               "name" : "testing",
               "env.root" : "/",
               "host" : "ip-10-12-68-170.b2c.test.com",
               "sin" : "sin.80",
               "env.description" : "Content Author Preview"
            }
         }
      },
      "ip-10-12-108.27.b2c.test.com" : {
         "environment" : {
            "esbqav" : {
               "ip" : "ip-10-12-108.27",
               "name" : "espv",
               "env.root" : "/",
               "host" : "ip-10-12-108.27.b2c.test.com",
               "sin" : "sin.0",
               "env.description" : "QA"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
for ip, ip_dict in json['host'].items():
    for hostname, hostname_dict in ip_dict['environment'].items():
        name = hostname_dict['name']
        print (ip, hostname, name)
```

The following code is equivalent, but iterates over just the keys and not the key,value pairs:

```
for ip in json['host']:
    for hostname in json['host'][ip]['environment']:
        name = json['host'][ip]['environment'][hostname]['name']
        print (ip, hostname, name)
```